# ADF - Mapping Data Flow has source file name with ':' character in it and gets error message

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am working with an ADF Mapping Data Flow.

The files in the dataset that I need to process are named in a format like this:
SS_Instagram_Posts_2020-11-10T16_45_14.9490665Z

When I set this in the source and look at the Data Preview I get this error message.

```
    at Source 'source1': java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: SS_Instagram_Posts_2020-11-10T16:44:39.6950865Z.json
```

I found a [microsoft page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/172845/relative-path-in-absolute-uri-error-while-setting.html)   that reports that the ':' character in the filename is the issue.

I have a massive amount of files in this format, so is there a forthcoming fix or a workaround that will allow me to use my current files as they are named with the timestamp????

[image: error]

Answer (score 0):

File names with these special characters are only supported in dataflows running in Synapse workspace not in ADF.

Comment: Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: This is limitation exists with Databricks spark but not with Synapse spark.

Comment: Is there any plan to fix/patch this 'limitation' for ADF?

Comment: ADF will have an option to use Synapse spark but those timelines are not immediate.

Answer (score 0):

I tested a json file dataset with same name as you, but haven't met this error.

Source dataset:
[image]

Just from the error message, your file name is **SS_Instagram_Posts_2020-11-10T16_45_14.9490665Z.json**, but in the expression , the file name is **SS_Instagram_Posts_2020-11-10T16:44:39.6950865Z.json**, the difference of the date format which caused the error.
[image]

Please rebuild your Wildcard paths expression to change the date format.